# Smart knapsack split algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, split, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Suppose we have to fill a sack with items based on the Threshold split. 
It should take the minimum values of sack to fill all the items.

Ex: when capacity of sack (Threshold) is set to 15 kg:

- Item  1: 10 kg
- Item  2: 8 kg
- Item  3: 7 kg

Based on smart split it should be

- Sack 1: Item 2: 8 kg, Item 3: 7 kg
- Sack 2: Item 1 :10 kg

I tried this using knapsack algorithm (with modifications) but no luck.

Comment: @OleV.V. Your comment is only marginally helpful.

Comment: @OleV.V. I tried looking for the answer but couldn't find any. Can you provide me a proper keywords for this to be found?